# Combine totals for old & new job #s

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that contains expense & invoice values. Some job #s actually have 2 job #s--an old & new job #. I need to sum the expense & invoice values for the job #s that have both old & new job #s; the result needs to be one row. I then need to delete the row that has the new job # entries.

I have an excel file that lists expenses & invoice totals for each job. In my code this is crcy:

```
Job#    Expenses    Invoice
1          5            2
2         10            27
3         15            33
10        60            4
20        57            21
12         9            36
22        11            18
```

I then have an excel file that lists old & new job #s:

```
Job#    New Job#
10      20
11      21
12      22
```

I'm not too sure which Pandas operation(s) to utilize here, so I don't know what to try. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

# Pull in excel data
crcy = pd.read_excel('crcy1.xlsx')
jobs = pd.read_excel('jobs.xlsx')

# Merge on job#
df3 = crcy.merge(jobs, on='Job#', how='outer')
# Drop rows where new job # is pulled in but 
# has no Expense/Invoice entries.
df3 = df3.dropna(thresh=3)

print(df3)
```

Actual results:

```
Job#  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#
1       5.0      2.0       0.0
2      10.0     27.0       0.0
3      15.0     33.0       0.0
10     60.0      4.0      20.0
20     57.0     21.0       0.0
12      9.0     36.0      22.0
22     11.0     18.0       0.0
```

Desired results:

```
Job#  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#
1       5.0      2.0       0.0
2      10.0     27.0       0.0
3      15.0     33.0       0.0
10    117.0     25.0      20.0
12     20.0     54.0      22.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# left merge crcy with jobs to get them on the same row
df = crcy.merge(jobs, how='left')

print(df)

   Job#  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#
0     1         5        2       NaN
1     2        10       27       NaN
2     3        15       33       NaN
3    10        60        4      20.0
4    20        57       21       NaN
5    12         9       36      22.0
6    22        11       18       NaN

# then left merge with jobs again but this time match Job# on the left with New Job# on the right
df = df.merge(jobs, left_on='Job#', right_on='New Job#', how='left')

print(df)

   Job#_x  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#_x  Job#_y  New Job#_y
0       1         5        2         NaN     NaN         NaN
1       2        10       27         NaN     NaN         NaN
2       3        15       33         NaN     NaN         NaN
3      10        60        4        20.0     NaN         NaN
4      20        57       21         NaN    10.0        20.0
5      12         9       36        22.0     NaN         NaN
6      22        11       18         NaN    12.0        22.0

# fill the missing Job#_y with Job#_x
# you'll use this for grouping the old job # and summing it's expenses and invoices
df['Job#_y'].fillna(df['Job#_x'], inplace=True)

print(df)

   Job#_x  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#_x  Job#_y  New Job#_y
0       1         5        2         NaN     1.0         NaN
1       2        10       27         NaN     2.0         NaN
2       3        15       33         NaN     3.0         NaN
3      10        60        4        20.0    10.0         NaN
4      20        57       21         NaN    10.0        20.0
5      12         9       36        22.0    12.0         NaN
6      22        11       18         NaN    12.0        22.0

# do the same with the New Job#_x
df['New Job#_x'].fillna(df['Job#_x'], inplace=True)

print(df)

   Job#_x  Expenses  Invoice  New Job#_x  Job#_y  New Job#_y
0       1         5        2         1.0     1.0         NaN
1       2        10       27         2.0     2.0         NaN
2       3        15       33         3.0     3.0         NaN
3      10        60        4        20.0    10.0         NaN
4      20        57       21        20.0    10.0        20.0
5      12         9       36        22.0    12.0         NaN
6      22        11       18        22.0    12.0        22.0

# group on the Job#_y and New Job#_x since they have no nulls and sum the expenses and invoics
# then reset the index
df = df.groupby([
    'Job#_y',
    'New Job#_x',
])[[
    'Expenses',
    'Invoice',
]].sum().reset_index()

print(df)

   Job#_y  New Job#_x  Expenses  Invoice
0     1.0         1.0         5        2
1     2.0         2.0        10       27
2     3.0         3.0        15       33
3    10.0        20.0       117       25
4    12.0        22.0        20       54

# replace the _letters using .str.replace and regex=True
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'_[a-z]', '', regex=True)

print(df)

   Job#  New Job#  Expenses  Invoice
0   1.0       1.0         5        2
1   2.0       2.0        10       27
2   3.0       3.0        15       33
3  10.0      20.0       117       25
4  12.0      22.0        20       54

# set the New Job# to 0 if it equals the old Job#
df['New Job#'].mask(df['Job#'] == df['New Job#'], 0, inplace=True)

print(df)

   Job#  New Job#  Expenses  Invoice
0   1.0       0.0         5        2
1   2.0       0.0        10       27
2   3.0       0.0        15       33
3  10.0      20.0       117       25
4  12.0      22.0        20       54
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Rename the columns for easier reference
jobs.columns = ['Old Job#', 'New Job#']

# For each job, find if it has an old Job#
crcy = crcy.merge(jobs, left_on='Job#', right_on='New Job#', how='left')

# The Job# that goes into the report is the Old Job#, if it has that
crcy['Report Job#'] = crcy['Old Job#'].combine_first(crcy['Job#'])

crcy.groupby('Report Job#').agg({
    'Expenses': 'sum',
    'Invoice': 'sum',
    'Old Job#': 'first'
})
```

Result:

```
             Expenses  Invoice  Old Job#
Report Job#                             
1.0                 5        2       NaN
2.0                10       27       NaN
3.0                15       33       NaN
10.0              117       25      10.0
12.0               20       54      12.0
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! In the groupby statement I had to precede it with crcy = in order to get it to work.